# Is it possible to get index of selected items in DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to get the index of selected `Rows` in a `CheckBoxColumn`, but so far I don't see property `CheckedIndex` is that possible?

```
 public void LoadPartListView()
    {
        using (productionDataSet = new _KUKA_Sorting_Buffer_ProductionDataSet())
        {
            using (parT_PRODUCTION_LISTTableAdapter)
            {
                dataTable = new _KUKA_Sorting_Buffer_ProductionDataSet.PART_PRODUCTION_LISTDataTable();
                parT_PRODUCTION_LISTTableAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            partOrderListView.Add(new TestPartOrderListView
            {
                SortingTowerNumber = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.SORTING_TOWER].ToString(),
                CustomerOrderName = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.CUSTOMER].ToString(),
                CabinetName = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.UPI_ARTICLE].ToString(),
                PackageNumber = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.UPI_PACKAGE].ToString(),
                PartName = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.NAME].ToString(),
                Barcode = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.BARCODE].ToString(),
                LocationRow = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.FIRST_ROW].ToString(),
                LocationColumn = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[(int)ProductListTable.FIRST_COLUMN].ToString()
            });
        }
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkedColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkedColumn.HeaderText = "Check Items";
        advancedDataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkedColumn);

        //Get the checked indexes from checkedColumn

        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        switch (sortingTowerButtonPressed)
        {
            case 1:
                bindingSource.Filter = $"(Convert([SORTING_TOWER],System.String) IN ('{sortingTowerButtonPressed}'))";
                break;
            case 2:
                bindingSource.Filter = $"(Convert([SORTING_TOWER],System.String) IN ('{sortingTowerButtonPressed}'))";
                break;
            case 3:
                bindingSource.Filter = $"(Convert([SORTING_TOWER],System.String) IN ('{sortingTowerButtonPressed}'))";
                break;
            case 4:
                bindingSource.Filter = $"(Convert([SORTING_TOWER],System.String) IN ('{sortingTowerButtonPressed}'))";
                break;
        }
        advancedDataGridView1.Enabled = true;
        advancedDataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;


    }
```

should I do some `event` for that? I really need some help

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571231/my-table-adapter-is-returning-null-even-after-checking-that-the-query-is-correct/57571667#57571667 while I write a full answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using TableAdapters and strongly typed DataTable; your code shouldn't look like this. I linked an answer up there in the comments offering similar advice to someone else who was also accessing data in a strongly typed table, the hard way.

In short, your code should look more like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Count; i++)
    {
        var ro = dataTable[i]; //retrieve a strongly typed data row, not a base DataRow (do NOT use the .Rows property)

        partOrderListView.Add(new TestPartOrderListView
        {
            SortingTowerNumber = ro.SORTING_TOWER, //or whatever the column name is
            CustomerOrderName = ro.CUSTOMER, //column name etc
            ...
        });
    }
```

As to what I recommend you do for allowing the user to pick some rows out of a grid:

*Add a column to the strongly typed datatable, of type Boolean*

The datatable isn't supposed to be an exact copy of the table in the db; it can have its own properties and columns, computations etc that are nothing to do with the DB data. By adding a boolean column and then adding the column to a grid (either explicitly or by relying on the grid's `autogeneratecolumns = true` setting) the grid will gain a checkbox column that manipulates the value of the bool on the row.

The user can then tick the boxes as per their wants and press a button. The datagridview will have stored the booleans the user ticked in the datatable it was bound to, so you can simply iterate or filter the datatable. Let us suppose we called the column `UserChoseThisRowBoolean` when we added it to the datatable in the dataset:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Count; i++)
    {
        var ro = dataTable[i]; 
        if(!ro.UserChoseThisRowBoolean) //if the user didn't tick this row
          continue; //skip on
        partOrderListView.Add(new TestPartOrderListView
        {
            SortingTowerNumber = ro.SORTING_TOWER,
            CustomerOrderName = ro.CUSTOMER,
            ...
        });
    }
```

We could also hit it with a filter then iterate the dataview:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Filter = "[UserChoseThisRowBoolean] = True";
foreach(DataViewRow dvro in dataTable.DefaultView)  
  var ro = dvro.Row as YourDataRowType;
```

Or we could use LINQ:

```
dataTable.AsQueryable().Where(ro => ro.UserChoseThisRowBoolean)
```

But I'd probably prefer the loop form in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, paste inside a button click event to test

```
//Name of Grid View : dataGridView1
//Name of Column : CheckBoxColumn1


       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Place this code where you want to know the index
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value) == true) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Index " + i); // Show index in message box or add to a list for further processing 
                }

            }
            //
        }
```